# Unable to burn iso to disk on OSX DVD +R

Tags: mac, macosx

I keep getting an error when trying to burn the ISO to a 4.7 Gig memorex DVD +R I have downloaded the iso several times, not the case. I am using disk utility. Any suggestions?

Comment: While the question seems unrelated to Ubuntu, perhaps you can actually tell what is the error. Incase you suspect something is wrong with the ISO, instead of re-downloading, [check it for errors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Mac_OS_X).

Comment: Isn't that a one time record DVD? To record several times you need a RW

Comment: @mikewhatever Why do you think this is off-topic? **Zach:** Is this an Ubuntu ISO? Are you trying to burn it multiple times to the same DVD, or are you trying to burn it multiple times to multiple DVD's, or did you *download* the ISO file to your computer multiple times? What OS are you using? (Both Ubuntu and OS X have something called the Disk Utility.) What is your goal, and exactly what have you done to achieve it?

Comment: @EliahKagan The problem doesn't seem to be related to Ubuntu in any way. From the little info we have, it looks like something is wrong with OSX, the burning program, the DVD media or the DVDRom.

Comment: @mikewhatever We support creating Ubuntu installation media here, even when it is done with a non-Ubuntu OS. We support the *entire* installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try burning from command line:
Assuming that all you want to do is create a CD based on the ISO 9660 file system standard, you can quickly burn the CD using the following command:

```
cdrecord -v -pad speed=1 dev=0,0,0 src.iso
```

[source](http://sharkysoft.com/tutorials/linuxtips/cdcommands/)